# How can the canard configuration increase the aircraft's maneuverability?

Tags: fighter, canard, maneuverability

I know that in many of the fighter jets, there are canard configurations like in F16, SAAB Gripen etc and heard they increase the aircraft's maneuverability. Can anyone explains how a canard helps in increasing it?

Comment: They form a vortex which causes a pressure drop on the main wing which allows the aircraft to fly at 50 degree angles without stalling.

Comment: @Ethan, you can do the same with leading edge extensions. The advantage for manoeuvrability is mainly in the way longitudinal stability works.

Comment: @Simon that answer provides the advantages of unstable canard but my question is like how canard increases the maneuverability i.e what additional things are given by canard that are included in the design? I am not sure if i am able to explain what i am looking for.

Comment: F16 with canards?!?

Comment: Canards don't provide any advantage. Having an instable aircraft (with the CG being not between the wings center of lift and the tail horizontal stabilizers) gives more maneuverability, this is what such aircraft exist. But this requires canards for stabilization. Canards are *required* for maneuverability, but they are not the *cause* of it.